# Can't find include_path from browser but works in Terminal

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2

I am new to server admin and PHP so my apologies. This one really has me stuck. I rebooted the EC2 server but still no luck.

PHP File

```
<?php
require_once "System.php";
var_dump(class_exists('System', false));
?>
```

Terminal (It Works)

```
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-10-26-22 current]$ php phpcheck.php
bool(true)
```

Browser - it doesn't find the file

```
Warning: require_once(System.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /etc/httpd/opt/app/current/phpcheck.php on line 2 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.:/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear') in /etc/httpd/opt/app/current/phpcheck.php on line 2
```

Comment: are you sure the file can be read by the webserver user (which may or may not be the same user you are executing commandline operations with)? Do a `ls -al` from the command line and see what the permissions are.

Comment: the System.php has -rw-rw-r-- . How do I find out if my webserver user is different than my command line user?

Comment: i think if you do a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then access that file from a browser it should tell you what user executes the php process or which one apache runs as... depending on if php is running as cgi/suexec or as a basic module.

Comment: could it be that the server user is "root" while the command line user is "ec2-user"? The required file is actually a few dir levels up and away from the httpd dir. But I assume that should be OK, correct?

Comment: What user/group does it show as the owner of both files? if they are the same then it should work fine... if they are different then you might have change some things around... There could also be a preconfigured ACL on the web accessible DIR that is allowing access while the ACL doesnt exist on the dir that is up a level.

Answer (score 2):

When I typically have these problems, I simply add this:

`require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/System.php');`

That way you get a full path to the file.

However, your include_path looks a little wonky.
-kc